# Asp.Net-Core 2.1: ModelState errors using custom IInputFormater

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, modelstate

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I need to support a payload format, but the underlying model has changed quite drastically.

To achieve this, I read about custom `ModelBinder`, `InputFormater`, and a few different topics, and what I retained is that since the `Content-Type` would be `application/json`, the `JsonInputFormatter` would handle it, wouldn't know how to convert it, so would pass a null model to the API method.

I then decided to implement a custom `InputFormatter` that would only handle that model type for that `Content-Type`, and do a custom deserialization.

The problem I'm encountering is that if there is an error in that custom deserialization, I must to call `InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync()`, which doesn't allow me to pass information back to the caller to tell him what's wrong. If I was using the default `JsonInputformatter`, in the controller I could surface the the model state errors (ModelState.Values's Errors property) to the caller, but I can't find a way to achieve this.

**My question is**: How can I surface the errors I encounter while using the custom `IInputFormatter`?

Note: If I'm simply not using the right tools for custom deserialization, any pointer to the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to split model validation from deserialization? You can use the `ILogger` to report specifics from your `InputFormatter`, but work on the basis of performing a best-effort at deserializing the payload. Then either default model binder, or a custom one if required can be used to validate the model. Because InputFormatter runs before model binding, and because you don't get a `ModelBindingContext` until model binding, the only way to add model errors would be to have a state class injected into both areas, populated by InputFormmater and consumed by binder, I guess?

Comment: Both the `InputFormatterContext` and `ModelBindingContext` have access to `HttpContext`, so you should definitely be able to pass across state per my last sentence in previous comment (wanted to double check what injection was available). Hope that helps?

Comment: It sure helps. I'll try separating both "operation" as you mentioned in your first comment. It will be some work to do all of that, but that's to be expected when doing that kind of custom deserialization!